# Login to Wordpress blog using REST API?

Tags: wordpress, authentication, oauth-2.0

I am trying to login to Wordpress using REST protocol.

In the Wordpress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/sites/%24site/users/), the authentication part is not clearly explained.

Here: http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/
The documentation says,

```
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'client_id' => your_client_id,
    'client_secret' => your_client_secret_key,
    'grant_type' => 'password'
    'username' => your_wpcom_username,
    'password' => your_wpcom_password,
) );
```

But how to get client_id and password from a third party log in system. Here third party is our groups login and we are trying to apply this login to a wordpress blog.

Comment: I take it you have [read this](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/oauth2/) and it didn't help? Could you tell us what error you're getting and show us your code? (without your credentials of course)

Comment: @Okuma.Scott. I absolutely read it but I am confused over how to get the data from the third party. I have updated my answer. Please take a look

Comment: What third-party are you using? You should contact them on how to get the `client_id` and `password` from their system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REST can pull the user name and password data from the third party login. Its the third party who needs to provide you with instruction on how to access their server. OAuth2 supplies the information to REST without giving your exact username and password. So you need ask the third party to provide details on how to get the data.